# How to fix accessibility on a page "Buttons must have discernible text"

Tags: vuejs2, accessibility, axedevtools

I have installed axe dev tool. But when I scan the page i find this error "Ensures buttons have discernible text". If I inspect on dev tool and add aria-label on the button it goes away, but in my code I have used vue form datepicker. not sure how to handle that below is the code sample.

```
  <b-form-datepicker
      id="example-i18n-picker"
      v-model="value"
      v-bind="labels[locale] || {}"
      :locale="locale"
      :start-weekday="weekday"
      :show-decade-nav="showDecadeNav"
      :hide-header="hideHeader"
      class="mb-2"
     ></b-form-datepicker>
```

i tried adding aria-label="calender" to this b-form-datepicker but does not work that way.

Comment: Can you please post the generated HTML code? It’s unclear what the exact problem is. I’d guess the button simply shows an icon, and this icon does not have any accessible name.

Comment: If you run the example on https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker and run axe on that page, you get the same error. There's a <button> with an embedded <svg> that starts off good by having `role="img" aria-label="calendar"` on the <svg> but then they mess up and also have `aria-hidden="true"` so it hides the <svg> from providing the accessible name.  **How** to fix it with vuejs, I'm not sure.

Comment: Specifying `aria-label` on the <b-form-datepicker> just causes an aria-label to be inserted on the <div> container around the <button>.

Comment: There are a [bunch of `label-` props](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#component-reference) that apply to the datepicker but none of them affect the calendar button. They all seem to be applied to the actual calendar grid that displays.

Comment: If I combine all my comments, I might have an answer :-)  The [`button-content`](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker#__BVID__464__row_button-content) slot lets you customize the calendar button. I'm not familiar with html slots but that should be enough to do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments in your question, tried to check the source of the component and came up with below. Kindly try and let me know if it works for you:

```
 <b-form-datepicker
  id="example-i18n-picker"
  v-model="value"
  v-bind="labels[locale] || {}"
  :locale="locale"
  :start-weekday="weekday"
  :show-decade-nav="showDecadeNav"
  :hide-header="hideHeader"
  class="mb-2"
 >
  <template #button-content="{isHovered,hasFocus}">
    <template v-if="isHovered || hasFocus">
      <b-icon-calendar-fill />
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <b-icon-calendar />
    </template>
  </template>
</b-form-datepicker>
```

It uses the suggestion of @slugolicious to use `button-content` and also to remove `aria-hidden` attribute